# How can I prevent EF Core logging for a particular method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, abp

I have a method which saves two records with identical keys and therefore creates a duplicate key exception (as expected). ABP logs the exception.

Then, my try-catch block catches and logs the exception. This means there are multiple events in the log for the same error.

I want to stop ABP from logging exceptions for this particular method so that only my try-catch block logs the exception.

Is there a way to configure to only log top-level exceptions, or identify another way to suppress unwanted logging of exceptions?

ABP Framework 7, EF Core 7.

```
        try
        {
            // Insert it once
            await Repository.InsertAsync(document, autoSave: true);

            // Insert it again, which correctly fails with a unique
            // constraint violation on Id and CollectionId
            await Repository.InsertAsync(document, autoSave: true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // This gets logged correctly but two other exceptions also appear in the log before it. Only this should be logged:
            _logger.LogError(ex, "InsertAsync failed");
        }
```

I have researched the ABP docs but can't see how to suppress errors for the data layer.

Comment: Why does the method store two identical keys? That's a clear concurrency error. It's not expected at all. It's not even how Entity Framework works. There's no `Repository`, no `InserAsync`. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work which means it track *all* changes to its objects. When you call `Add` or `Update` on a detached object, that object isn't saved. It's added to the UoW in the Added or Modified state. Same with Remove. When you call `SaveChanges` *all* pending changes are persisted in a single transaction, or none. Dispose the DbContext and you discard all changes

Comment: Regardless of the repository pattern on top of the DBContext, which is a repository pattern implementation and unit of work (which I don't like and never use willingly, BTW), you can configure logging to suppress messages from any source contexts.  What's the context for the logged lines?

Comment: This has nothing to do with top-level exceptions and logs but misuse of EF Core. First of all, putting a low-level "repository" (it's actually a DAO) over a high level ORM/UoW is an ugly antipattern. The fact ABP uses this is doesn't mean much - ABP contains a lot of design problems caused by attempts to cover all buzzwords